# Kotlin - Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'P'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview, video-processing

I am using below video player library and have to play video from local url.

Library is here : https://github.com/halilozercan/BetterVideoPlayer

I have done :

```
private lateinit var mVv_gym_toor_video: BetterVideoPlayer

vv_gym_gallery_video.setSource(Uri.fromFile(file))
vv_gym_gallery_video.start()
```

I am getting **/storage/emulated/0/MyApp/Media/media_683c42.mp4** in **file**

In XML, I have taken as below :

```
                <com.halilibo.bvpkotlin.BetterVideoPlayer
                    app:bvp_showBottomProgressBar="false"
                    android:id="@+id/vv_gym_gallery_video"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_200"
                    app:bvp_autoPlay="false"
                    app:bvp_disableControls="false"
                    app:bvp_hideControlsOnPlay="true"
                    app:bvp_pauseDrawable="@drawable/bvp_action_pause"
                    app:bvp_playDrawable="@drawable/bvp_action_play"
                    app:bvp_restartDrawable="@drawable/bvp_action_restart"
                    app:bvp_captionSize="22sp"
                    app:bvp_captionColor="@color/color_app_theme_dark"
                    app:bvp_gestureType="SwipeGesture"
                    app:bvp_loop="false" />
```

But, getting below error :

```
Caused by: java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'P'
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Formatter.java:2781)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2811)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifierParser.<init>(Formatter.java:2624)
    at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2557)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2504)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2458)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2770)
    at com.halilibo.bvpkotlin.BetterVideoPlayer$Companion.log(BetterVideoPlayer.kt:1072)
    at com.halilibo.bvpkotlin.BetterVideoPlayer$Companion.access$log(BetterVideoPlayer.kt:1064)
    at com.halilibo.bvpkotlin.BetterVideoPlayer.prepare(BetterVideoPlayer.kt:480)
    at com.halilibo.bvpkotlin.BetterVideoPlayer.setSource(BetterVideoPlayer.kt:372)
    at com.gymowner.ui.my_gym.fragments.GymGalleryFragment.onActivityResult(GymGalleryFragment.kt:437)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:170)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7276)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
```

Comment: Did you get solution on this?

Comment: @piyushporiya Changed Video library. BetterVideoPlayer is no longer supported.

Comment: Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77988364/9133569