# Formatting a String with the character %

Tags: java, string, formatting

I was trying to format the String  "2%" using the following code `String.format("s%2", 2)` and I got java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'End of String'.

So with the above result commes the questing how can I add '%' as a member of the output on the String

Comment: The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) should help here. If I remember correctly you need to escape `%` by doubling. Also the conversion needs to start with a `%` so try`"%s%%"`.

Comment: Check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77988364/9133569

Answer (score 2):

You represent a literal `%` by doubling it up...put `%%`.

To print "2%", where the 2 comes from the integer passed in as an argument to the `format()` call, you want this:

```
String str = String.format("%d%%", 2);

System.out.println(str);
```

Result:

```
2%
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape unwanted %. Otherwise String will take it as arguments. To escape single percent sign you need to add another percent character behind it ie. %%.